# vue.js conditional rendering in tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I have a table populated by `vue` where I want to show rows if there's data, or a row with "no results" if there's no data. Here's a basic look at it in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ox0ozs5g/1/).

Why does the `v-else` row continue to show even when the `v-if` condition is met?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately `v-if` and `v-for` are not working together. You could move `v-if` one level higher, like this:

```
<tbody v-if="my_tasks.length">
    <tr id="retriever-task-{{ index }}" v-for="(index, task) in my_tasks" >
        <td>{{ task.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ task.type }}</td>
        <td>{{ task.frequency }}</td>
        <td>{{ task.status }}</td>
        <td><i v-on:click="deleteTask(index, task.id)" class="fa fa-trash"></i></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<tbody v-else>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="6">No tasks found.</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

You can also use pseudoelement `template`:

```
<template v-if="my_tasks.length">
    <tr id="retriever-task-{{ index }}" v-for="(index, task) in my_tasks" >
        <td>{{ task.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ task.type }}</td>
        <td>{{ task.frequency }}</td>
        <td>{{ task.status }}</td>
        <td><i v-on:click="deleteTask(index, task.id)" class="fa fa-trash"></i></td>
    </tr>
</template>
<template v-else>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="6">No tasks found.</td>
    </tr>
</template>
```

Comment: I've forget about this!! Btw, you saved my night @Randall, thanks
+1 for the question also

Comment: this quickly turns into v-else-if hell if each column is different in terms of what elements it contains and has action buttons etc etc, any better method ?

Comment: In this case you should probably move that rows to subcomponents.

Answer (score 3):

From the Vuejs docs "The v-else element must immediately follow the v-if or v-show element - otherwise it will not be recognized." - https://vuejs.org/guide/conditional.html.  It looks like the additional vue data binding attributes following the v-if are breaking it (e.g. v-for and v-on).

You can use v-show instead.  For example:

```
    <tr v-show="!my_tasks.length">
      <td colspan="6">No tasks found.</td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: No, this has nothing to do with it. The expression "must immediatly follow" refers to the HTML elements of the same level. Wahtever is nested inside, does not matter on that context. Only the `v-if` on the same level is the problem, as yariiash explained above. Other directives (`v-on` etc.) would be fine.

Comment: Thanks.  However, using v-show works well with the OP's example.

Answer (score 1):

yariash is right about the `v-if` and `v-for`.  You could do as he suggested or just change the `v-else` to the reverse of the `v-if`, i.e. `v-if="!my_tasks.length"`.